# How do you track users who click on "Add to Chrome" but don't click on "Add Extension"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When people visit the Chrome Store to download an extension, I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to know how many users click the "Add to Chrome" button **and** how many users then click the "Add Extension" button after clicking "Add to Chrome". We are trying to figure out how many people drop off between "Add to Chrome" and "Add Extension" dialog pop up. Anyone know if this is something we can track and/or Google tracks and makes available?